# Why are my event listeners either always on or always off?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I made a set of event listeners:

```
var fname = document.getElementById("fName");
var ssn = document.getElementById("ss");
var zip = document.getElementById("zip");
var hphone = document.getElementById("hphone");
var wphone = document.getElementById("wphone");
var mphone = document.getElementById("mphone");
var dob = document.getElementById("dateObirth");
if (ssn.addEventListener) {
    console.log("Validating");
    fname.addEventListener("change", validatefname, false);
    ssn.addEventListener("change", validateSSN, false); 
    zip.addEventListener("change", validateZip, false); 
    hphone.addEventListener("change", validateHPhone, false);
    wphone.addEventListener("change", validateWPhone, false);
    mphone.addEventListener("change", validateMPhone, false);
    dob.addEventListener("change", validateDOB, false);
} else if (ssn.attachEvent) {
    console.log("Validating_02");
    fname.attachEvent("onchange", validatefname);
    ssn.attachEvent("onchange", validateSSN);
    zip.attachEvent("onchange", validateZip);
    hphone.attachEvent("onchange", validateHPhone);
    wphone.attachEvent("onchange", validateWPhone);
    mphone.attachEvent("onchange", validateMPhone);
    dob.attachEvent("onchange", validateDOB);
}
```

the elements are inputs in my html file and the ids are all correct.
in this instance the different validate functions never happen. even when I change the info inside the input fields, they never run like they are supposed to.

now if I write the code like this;

```
var fname = document.getElementById("fName");
var ssn = document.getElementById("ss");
var zip = document.getElementById("zip");
var hphone = document.getElementById("hphone");
var wphone = document.getElementById("wphone");
var mphone = document.getElementById("mphone");
var dob = document.getElementById("dateObirth");
if (ssn.addEventListener) {
    console.log("Validating");
    fname.addEventListener("change", validatefname(), false);
    ssn.addEventListener("change", validateSSN(), false); 
    zip.addEventListener("change", validateZip(), false); 
    hphone.addEventListener("change", validateHPhone(), false);
    wphone.addEventListener("change", validateWPhone(), false);
    mphone.addEventListener("change", validateMPhone(), false);
    dob.addEventListener("change", validateDOB(), false);
} else if (ssn.attachEvent) {
    console.log("Validating_02");
    fname.attachEvent("onchange", validatefname);
    ssn.attachEvent("onchange", validateSSN);
    zip.attachEvent("onchange", validateZip);
    hphone.attachEvent("onchange", validateHPhone);
    wphone.attachEvent("onchange", validateWPhone);
    mphone.attachEvent("onchange", validateMPhone);
    dob.attachEvent("onchange", validateDOB);
}
```

with a set of parentheses after each validate function, then the validate functions will always occur regardless of if I have entered any data into the input fields or changed said data to supposedly be correct.

so basically, the one thing that is broken is whether the validate functions always occur regardless of if I've entered information or they never occur.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I just want the functions to occur only if I enter information into the input field and or change preexisting data.

Here is one of the validate functions, they all are pretty much the same:

```
function validateSSN(){
console.log("Validate ssn");
var ssn = document.getElementById("ss");
var errorDiv = document.getElementById("ssError");
var ssnPattern = /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
try {
    if(ssnPattern.test(ssn.value) === false) {
        throw "Please provide a valid Social Security Number.";
    }

    ssn.style.background = "";
    errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
    errorDiv.style.display = "none";
}
catch(msg) {
    errorDiv.innerHTML = msg;
  errorDiv.style.display = "block";
  // change input style
  ssn.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide the code for at least one of the validate functions? It might be worth just seeing what happens with just one field and validate function.

Comment: Do you have the `required` attribute assigned to inputs?

Comment: Also, why are you using `.attachEvent()`? IE will become extinct by next month and IE8 hasn't had support for the last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see with a more limited example it appears to work:

```js
function validateSSN(){
  console.log("Validate ssn");
  var ssn = document.getElementById("ss");
  var errorDiv = document.getElementById("ssError");
  var ssnPattern = /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
  try {
      if(ssnPattern.test(ssn.value) === false) {
          throw "Please provide a valid Social Security Number.";
      }

      ssn.style.background = "";
      errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
      errorDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
  catch(msg) {
    errorDiv.innerHTML = msg;
    errorDiv.style.display = "block";
    // change input style
    ssn.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
  }
}

var ssn = document.getElementById("ss");
if (ssn.addEventListener) {
    console.log("Adding event listener");
    ssn.addEventListener("change", validateSSN, false);
}
```

```html
<input id="ss" />
<div id="ssError"></div>
```

As for why the version with parentheses always run, that's because they're being called when the event listeners are being created rather than when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly I did to fix this problem, I just continued working on other parts of the website and the validation code suddenly started working. Sorry I don't have a specific answer to resolve the issue for anyone in the future, but my best suggestion is just muddle through and work on other aspects of the project and broken stuff may just snap into place and work properly.